# How to remove Bing map (and all child controls) from tab order

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Does the Bing maps control (Microsoft.Maps.Map) offer an API for removing itself (and its child controls) from the tab order?

Alternatively, is there an appropriate callback (post rendering) I can use to set the tabIndex recursively on all elements once the map has rendered itself?

**NB**: I've seen there are options at construction time for specifying whether to render the map type selector/locate me button/zoom buttons. But lets assume we want to render those controls just remove them from the tab order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve it using a MutationObserver:

```
var mapElem = document.getElementById("map");

let deferredClearTabIndexEvent: number | undefined;

if (mapElem !== null) {
    var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };
    var callback = () => {
        if (deferredClearTabIndexEvent === undefined) {
            deferredClearTabIndexEvent = window.setTimeout(() => {
                var elements = mapElem!.querySelectorAll("a, button, input, select, textarea, [tabindex]")
                for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
                    elements[i].setAttribute("tabIndex", "-1");
                }

                deferredClearTabIndexEvent = undefined;
            }, 0);
        }
    };

    var observer = new MutationObserver(callback);
    observer.observe(mapElem, config);
}
```